# Largest set of cocircular points

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, computational-geometry

> Given $n$ points with integer coordinates in the plane, determine the maximum number of points that lie on the same circle (on its circumference, not its interior).

This can be done in $O(n^3)$ easily by trying $\binom{n}{3}$ combinations of points and counting the number of occurrences of all circles found with hash tables.

**Question:** Is there an algorithm with $o(n^3)$ time?

**Bonus question:** Is there an algorithm which has a better performance than $O(n^3)$ assuming the maximum size of the (individual) coordinates is $c\times w$ where $w$ is the size of a machine Word and $c$ a constant?

Comment: You might want to rethink this as an image processing/computer vision-type problem. IIRC there are scale-invariant versions of the Circle Hough Transform, for example.

Comment: @Pseudonym Hm.. the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform) mentions that for unknown radius "we can iterate through possible radiuses and for each radius", so the huge downside of that method would be that the complexity is now around $O(NM^2)$ , where $M$ is the maximum magnitude of a coordinate. But maybe there is some way to get something out of image processing.

Comment: Yes, you'd probably want some more current research. By the way, if this is a real-world problem that you're trying to solve, don't forget randomised algorithms, like RANSAC and its variants.

Comment: My guess is no. A lower bound may perhaps be found using the projection [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs268-09-winter/notes/basic.pdf). Project  $(x_i,y_i)$  to $(x_i,y_i,x_i^2+y_i^2)$, so that three points are concyclic iff their projections are coplanar. So an $o(n^3)$ test for concylicity reduces to one for coplanarity.

Comment: Just to note that  we do have [$o(n^3)$ algorithms that solves the corresponding problem when circles are replaced by lines and cocircular by collinear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386695/maximum-collinear-points-in-a-plane)

Comment: Your problem runs into a very serious problem of **rational** data and **irrational** data. If you do not allow some **margin of error** then hardly any circle contains more than 3 or 4 rational coordinate points.

Comment: @ThinhD.Nguyen There can be many points with rational coordinates on a circle. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325650/prove-that-a-circle-exists-for-which-at-least-n-in-mathbbn-points-have-int

Comment: @Apass.Jack, and that can be generalised to $O(n^2)$ for any fixed radius, assuming $O(1)$ hashing. Unfortunately, the radius doesn't have nice bounds: it can be a lot more than the size of the bounding box of the points.

Comment: I take it the circles don't have to be centered at the origin?

Comment: @vonbrand its only one circle that has to be found... if the center is bound to be in the origin we may just use a hashmap to count magnitude frequencies in linear time.

Comment: I don't believe we can improve on $O(n^3)$, since the equivalent problem of finding the most points that are collinear cannot be done better than $O(n^2)$: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179581/what-is-the-most-efficient-algorithm-to-find-a-straight-line-that-goes-through-m